# Having an issue figuring out where to do calculations before using Upsert in mongodb

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I'm using the angular-fullstack generator so there's 7 files in one endpoint (index, index.spec, orders.controller, orders.events, orders.integration, orders.model, and orders.socket). I'm not sure where to do computation to store in the fields when there is a PUT/Upsert. All the examples that I can google either use virtual fields or have generic code to do the computation. I know the computation I need to do but have no idea where to put it using this generator.

After a bit more searching this morning, I ***think*** what I want is to use getters/setters?

Answer (score 0):

It's working in the controller as I presumed but i'm not sure if it's the best place to put these simple

```
function doCalcsSingle(res) {
  var tOrderitems = 0;
  var tRecitems = 0;
  var tMissingitems = 0;
  var today = new Date();
  for(var i = 0; i < res.body.items.length; i++) {
    res.body.items[i].missingItems = res.body.items[i].numOfOrdItems - res.body.items[i].numOfRecItems;
    if(res.body.items[i].missingItems < 0 || !res.body.items[i].missingItems) {
      res.body.items[i].missingItems = 0;
    }
    res.body.items[i].totalPrice = res.body.items[i].numOfOrdItems * res.body.items[i].unitPrice;
    tOrderitems = tOrderitems + res.body.items[i].numOfOrdItems;
    tRecitems = tRecitems + res.body.items[i].numOfRecItems;
    tMissingitems = tMissingitems + res.body.items[i].missingItems;
    if(tMissingitems < 0 || !tMissingitems) {
      tMissingitems = 0;
    }
  }
  res.body.totalOrdItems = tOrderitems;
  res.body.totalRecItem = tRecitems;
  res.body.totalItemsMissing = tMissingitems;
  res.body.lastUpdated = today;
  if(tMissingitems <= 0) {
    res.body.activeOrder = false;
    res.body.completedDate = today;
  } else {
    res.body.activeOrder = true;
  }
  return res;
}
```